# Copying And Pasting Assets

Tags: copy

This is a total noob question as I'm still learning. So apologies it;s a steep learning curve this Xcode business...

How do I copy and paste an auto image scroller (along with it's ViewController) that was created in a friends Xcode project and place it into the Xcode project that I'm currently working in?

When I copy and paste the autoscroller containers along with the ViewController all the links to the ViewControllers, Outlets, ect won't link up. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code with specific details and issue

Comment: Thanks. It's not really a code issue but more an issue of how to integrate the work that was done by another Dev and incorporating their work into my Storyboard. In this case it was a Auto Scroller.

Any help would be great :)